# % sign before library in Ipython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

Does anyone know what the % sign in front of a library means in Ipython?
In a caffe tutorial there are the following first lines of a python script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

What does the third row `%matplotlib inline` do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A leading `%` means it is a built-in [`magic command` in `iPython`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#magic-command-system)

In this case, [`%matplotlib inline`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib) enables the inline backend for usage with the IPython Notebook